# set property of new instance

Tags: forms, properties, instance

thank you for helping.

First, I created a form with a (user defined) property.
as see below

```
public partial class nfrmtableitem : Form
{
    private DataRow _datarow;
    public DataRow U_Table_Row { get { return _datarow; } set { _datarow = value; } }

    public nfrmtableitem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And I create second form with property as type of Form.
as see below

```
public partial class nftableshow : Form
{
    private DataTable _datatable;
    public DataTable U_DataTable { get { return _datatable; } set { _datatable = value; } }

    private Form _inputform1;
    public Form U_DGV_InputForm1 { get { return _inputform1; } set { _inputform1 = value; } }
}
```

when call it:
any where

```
nftableshow newfrmtableshow = new nftableshow()
{
    Name = "newfrmtableshow",
    Text = "Show the table",
    MdiParent = this,
    U_DGV_InputForm1 = new nfrmtableitem(),
};
newfrmtableshow.Show();
```

But I can not use the first form property in second form.
and the property is not in instance.

```
//the button in second form
private void button1_Click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form f1 = _inputform1 as Form;
    /*
     * {
     * U_Table_Row = db.maindataset.Tables["customer"].NewRow(),
     * };
     */
    f1.Show();
}
```

Question:
How can I use the First form with specific (user defined) property in second form.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use dot notation to access the property of the first form. Try using

```
 //the button in second form
 private void button1_Click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  Form f1 = _inputform1 as Form;

 {
 f1.U_Table_Row = db.maindataset.Tables["customer"].NewRow(),
 };

f1.Show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you I try it but not true